# presenting a simple introduction to variation Bayes

Tags: psychometrics, teaching, variational-bayes, presentation

I am planning to present a simple introduction to variational Bayesian inference during a lab research meet (45 mins). My audience is mainly from a psychometrics, psychology, educational sciences background who have a basic idea of Bayesian inference and mainly work with SPSS. Computational methods are relatively rare here and not discussed.

I was wondering how do I structure the presentation, I would lose the audience if I make it math heavy, yet, it is hard to talk about variational methods hiding the math.

I do not want to present it as a *look, a cool method*, but more to make people aware that there are alternatives to MCMC if they want to do Bayesian inference (in a large dataset and complex model context).
Any suggestions would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was in a similar position a couple years ago and stumbled upon [this](https://kaybrodersen.github.io/talks/Brodersen_2013_03_22.pdf). The author has lifted a lot of the material straight from Bishop (ch. 10) but oh well. What I thought was quite good for at least the first portion was it serving as a decent look at the topic from a heuristic point of view (pros and cons) with some math present as well. I found it a good source of motivation.

I'd share what I actually did, but alas I don't have the presentation any more.  Good luck!